# Assigning $PWD/* to another variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to assign `$PWD/*` to another variable.  I tried the following:
`dir=${PWD/*}` and `dir=${PWD}/*`, but neither of these two worked.

Results:

```
$ dir=${PWD/*}
$ for i in $dir; do echo $i; done
#nothing

$ dir=${PWD}/*
$ for i in $dir; do echo $i; done
/current/working/dir/*
```

Expected results:

```
$ for i in $dir; do echo $i; done

/current/working/dir/dir1
/current/working/dir/dir2
/current/working/dir/somefile
..etc
```

I would appreciate some help!  Thank you.

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the results I get.

Comment: try `echo $dir`. then try `ls`.

Comment: I want to assign $PWD to another variable.  Please read the post again.

Comment: i'm trying to help you troubleshoot the problem. it sounds like your directory is empty.

Comment: it's not.... running $PWD/* works well but assigning to another variable is the problem here.

Comment: BTW, when you reproduced the problem, was your directory name really of the form `/current/working/dir`? If your shell really was bash (as opposed to, say, zsh), the issue implies a directory name with spaces or glob characters (unless a nondefault IFS value was active). Whereas if your shell is really zsh, tag for zsh, not bash; they're not mutually compatible.

Comment: I was running it on bash.  I don't understand what are you trying to prove(?). And no, none of my dirs/files had a space.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you had a problem with your original code. While I was able to offer a more robust alternative, that doesn't mean the exact failure mechanism of the original is obvious -- at least, not without details that weren't included in the question. If you were really using bash, were in a non-empty directory with no spaces in its name, had the shell's configuration flags at their defaults, and had an IFS value that wasn't changed to something pathological, `dir=${PWD}/*; for i in $dir; do echo $i; done` should have appeared to work as you expected.

Comment: What is the output of `set -o|grep noglob` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assign the *results* to an *array*.

...and quote all your parameter expansions (while leaving glob characters you want expanded unquoted). That is:

```
values=( "$PWD"/* )
[[ -e ${values[0]} || -L ${values[0]} ]] || values=( ) # handle no-result case
echo "${#values[@]} items found in directory $PWD"
for item in "${values[@]}"; do
  echo "$item"
done
```

The above works even if your `PWD` contains whitespace, which will break the unquoted expansion model followed by the original code in the question.

Comment: Don't miss the `shopt -s nullglob` option or meet with surprise if `"$PWD"` directory is empty.

Comment: @LéaGris can `PWD` be empty?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the directory it points to can be empty

Comment: @LéaGris, ...amended appropriately (not actually setting `nullglob`, but handling the case where it matters).